# Return range with first and last character in string

Tags: ios, string, swift

I have a string: `"Hey @username that's funny"`. For a given string, how can I search the string to return all ranges of string with first character `@` and last character  to get the `username`?

I suppose I can get all indexes of @ and for each, get the `substringToIndex` of the next space character, but wondering if there's an easier way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your username can contain only letters and numbers, you can use regular expression for that:

```
let s = "Hey @username123 that's funny"

if let r = s.rangeOfString("@\\w+", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch) {
  let name = s.substringWithRange(r) // @username123"
}
```

Comment: That's technically correct, so I'm blaming myself for not being clearer. But if there are multiple "usernames", then rangeOfString will only return the first occurrence. Is there a way to capture all rangesOfString?

Comment: dperk, you can use NSRegularExpression and its matchesInString method for that

Answer (score 1):

@Vladimir's answer is correct, but if you're trying to find multiple occurrences of "username", this should also work:

```
    let s = "Hey @username123 that's funny"

    let ranges: [NSRange]

    do {
         // Create the regular expression.
         let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "@\\w+", options: [])

         // Use the regular expression to get an array of NSTextCheckingResult.
         // Use map to extract the range from each result.
         ranges = regex.matchesInString(s, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, s.characters.count)).map {$0.range}
   }
   catch {
         // There was a problem creating the regular expression
         ranges = []
   }

   for range in ranges {

         print((s as NSString).substringWithRange(range))

   }
```